# GDBuss.Error.org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error

Tags: raspbian

I am using a Raspberry PI 3B+ for learning Python programming and some hardware design for PI3. I hadn’t turned it on for a while. Recently, I powered it up and it booted just fine. The second power up cycle, on startup, it displayed the error message:  “GDBuss.Error.org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.NotSupported:Operation not supported”
I noticed that when attempting a shutdown, the dialog box for shutdown appears but nothing happens when I select shutdown (or reboot, or log out). However opening a terminal window and typing “sudo shutdown now” does shut down the Pi. Additionally, it does not recognize a USB drive so I cannot move my files to another device. I did an update to the operating system but it did not help. I have created another bootable SD card with the latest Raspbian OS (Raspbian OS GNU/Linux Version 9 stretch) and it boots fine. If only I could use a USB stick to move my files from the old SD card to the new, I would be fine.
I cannot find this error on the raspberry Pi troubleshooting forum nor this exact issue on this forum. Any help would be appreciated to correct the root cause of this error.

Comment: Have you seen this https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/gdbus-error-org-freedesktop-policykit1-error-failed-4175427513/ or searched for the full error message on google? You can recover files from it using a Linux system (even your Pi and an external card reader.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply to my post. I have indeed searched for the complete error message on Google with no results. Some hits on the general topic of PolicyKit1 error but none that were applicable to my error. I tried to place the SD card in a USB reader and plugged it into a Unbuntu machine to read the files. I could see operating system files but not my personal files in /pi folder. Guessing it's a permission thing. I did, however, recover my files by using Chromium, logging into my webmail account and sending my files to myself using email attachments. I will follou on the link you included.